# Excel VLOOKUP functioning incorrectly

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I am currently in the middle of a few projects entailing the import of data sets from gov sites into company models.

Software: Microsoft Excel 2016

Process:
Download Dataset
Transpose Dataset H -> V (to match out model's display)
Assign numerical value to each row

Problem:
when using VLOOKUP to search for a cell (Name of location) [in array b] in array A and return corresponding assigned number value.  The value returned is more times than not, in correct.

Example:
Search #1:
Searching for the numerical value for "Anchorage, AK" 
`=VLOOKUP(C3,'V. Combo'!$D$3:$F$384,3,1)`  -{Cell C3 contains "Anchorage, AK"}
Returned value = "1" 
Correct Value = "1" <-This is correct

Search #3
Searching for the numerical value for "Huntsville, AL"
`=VLOOKUP(C5,'V. Combo'!$D$3:$F$384,3,1)' {See above}
Returned Value = "134"
Correct Value = "12" <- This is incorrect

Any ideas why the lookup will state incorrect values?

TIA

Comment: When using `1` as the forth criterion the data must be sorted on the look up column in ascending order.  I believe though with your examples you want `FALSE` or `0` in the forth criterion.

Comment: Data in both sets are in ascending order.
I have use "0" returned w/N?A

Comment: Check your data for unprintable characters,  the VLOOKUP when using `0` is looking for an exact match.  If it is sorted then it will return the value where alphabetically it falls in the lookup range, if it does not find an exact match.